# Image size is not increasing as the size of image of image increasing in xml

Tags: android, xml, image

[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2FfX.png)

Before reading the question,check out the image. Here I want to increase the size of leftmost circle but it is fixed at this size irrespective to image size. Can anyone help.

Here is the code:-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/prescription_folder"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <!-- first segment-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/folder_image_first"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_circle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/folder"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_folder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



        <!-- <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/folder_image_first"
             android:src="@drawable/images_with_folder"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/no_of_files_first"
            android:text="10"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <!--Middle Text i.e folder name and date-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--android:text="Rx/Prescription"-->

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="ABC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#03C9A9"
            android:id="@+id/last_updated_date_first"
            android:text="date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Last Segement-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/alert_button_pres"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do u mean by saying it has a fixed size? what did u tried for increasing its size?

Comment: I uploaded the higher pixel image.

Comment: u didnt answer my question. what did u done?

Comment: I did @shadoWalker I have uploaded bigger size picture. as the image size is set to wrap content

Answer (score 0):

it's because the circle natural size it's smallest than the image inside, and Android doesn't works with percents,

1. the solution is setting the size of the circle, and the size of the image.
2. Other solutions is draw the circle with coords, and put a linear layout inside, and put the size of the image with fill content